# Automatic retry connection to broker by spring-rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have read this fragment of docs:

> RabbitMQ Automatic Connection/Topology recovery
>
> Since the first version of Spring AMQP, the framework has provided its
>   own connection and channel recovery in the event of a broker failure.
>   Also, as discussed in Section 3.1.10, “Configuring the broker”, the
>   RabbitAdmin will re-declare any infrastructure beans (queues etc) when
>   the connection is re-established. It therefore does not rely on the
>   Auto Recovery that is now provided by the amqp-client library. Spring
>   AMQP now uses the 4.0.x version of amqp-client, which has auto
>   recovery enabled by default. Spring AMQP can still use its own
>   recovery mechanisms if you wish, disabling it in the client, (by
>   setting the automaticRecoveryEnabled property on the underlying
>   RabbitMQ connectionFactory to false). However, the framework is
>   completely compatible with auto recovery being enabled. This means any
>   consumers you create within your code (perhaps via
>   RabbitTemplate.execute()) can be recovered automatically.

I am not sure If I correctly understand. In my `application.properties` I have defined port and host. During starting my spring-boot app it successfully established connection and all necessary beans to communicate with queue.

However,  what in case when during start my app broker is shutdown and it will be launched five minutes after starting of app ?   Does `spring-rabbitmq` manage to reconnect and define all beans ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. Spring AMQP manages the re-connection and recovery automatically.

This subject isn't related to bean definitions. If you talk about Broker entities declaration, then yes, that are processed really on the connection establishing.

Comment: In simple language listener will be able to get messages after successful reconnecting ?

Comment: Something like that. Look here as well: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#_resilience_recovering_from_errors_and_broker_failures

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will read about it. And tomorrow I will check it in practice, in case of problems I give you a sign!  Beside of reading this reference I should roughly read code of `spring-rabbitmq`, I think

Comment: one thing else:  Before I check it tomorrow, are you exactly understand my use case? In properties I have host and port. If broker is shutdown, then **during launching/starting/mvn spring-boot:run** spring-boot app - should it start or it throw exception and turn off ?

Comment: There are https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples. You can play with start/stop RabbitMQ on one of them.

Comment: The app will start, you will see some reconnection logs and when you start broker back, the consumer will start to handle messages from the queue

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, you just have to put a property on the connection factory configuration.

As per the article [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) set `factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);` and `factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);` on the factory and the rabbit client will try to reconnect when the rabbit server is down or the connection is lost.

Because you are using spring configuration for the connection factory your connection factory will be like the following

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="somehost"/>
    <property name="username" value="guest"/>
    <property name="password" value="guest"/>
    <property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="networkRecoveryInterval" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Connection factory reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#connections)

Comment: Ok, can it be configured from `application.properties` ??

Comment: @HaskellFun definitely. Spring takes the system properties and also properties from the application, so, you can use it in place of 10000 in the above example.

Comment: I am not sure if I can configure it from this file: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html However, I can deal with  JavaConfig.Tell me please, if your configuration meet with my expectations: **During launching**  spring-boot app we can see in logs that there is no connection, and after 5 minutes (broker was died since 5 minutes) it establish connection and sends messages to Listener.

Comment: @HaskellFun Did you try to turn off the broker once the spring boot app is up? The properties I mentioned works when the broker is shutdown after the boot app is deployed.

Comment: There is little mistake: class name must be `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory` as this class has properties _automaticRecoveryEnabled_ and _networkRecoveryInterval_. This is driver connection factory. And this factory instance needs to be  passed as constructor arg to spring's `CachingConnectionFactory`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connections will be recreated when the broker is back on line. The default recovery interval is 5 seconds. You can change the recovery interval by setting `container.setRecoveryInterval(30000);` where `container` is a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. Setting recovery interval in the underlying connection factory `cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setNetworkRecoveryInterval(int)` seems not reflecting.