# How to reconnect with Rabbit MQ after server goes down?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a spring-boot application that uses Rabbit RPC. 
The problem is that if the app starts, then Rabbit server goes down, the application doesn't reconnect with the server. And if the app starts while the rabbit server is down, it fails and doesn't attempt to reconnect to Rabbit after the Rabbit goes up again.
Here is code of configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
private String rabbitmqHost;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.queue}")
private String rabbitmqQueue;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
private String rabbitmqUsername;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
private String rabbitmqPassword;

private final CommentsServiceRpc commentsServiceRpc;


public RabbitConfiguration(final CommentsServiceRpc commentsServiceRpc) {
    this.commentsServiceRpc = commentsServiceRpc;
}

@Bean
public Connection rabbitmqConnection() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(rabbitmqHost);
    factory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername);
    factory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
    return factory.newConnection();
}

@Bean
public Channel rpcChanel() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    Connection connection = rabbitmqConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare(rabbitmqQueue, false, false, false, null);
    return channel;
}

@Bean("commentsJsonRpcServer")
@Lazy(false)
public JsonRpcServer commentsJsonRpcServer() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    JsonRpcServer jsonRpcServer = new JsonRpcServer(rpcChanel(), rabbitmqQueue, CommentsServiceRpc.class,
            commentsServiceRpc);
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            jsonRpcServer.mainloop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }).start();
    return jsonRpcServer;
}
}
```

How can I tell Spring-boot to try to reconnect, if Rabbit server fails and restarts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the first thing about Spring Boot, but [this answer looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42981983/1466825) -

---

I've had a similar issue, you just have to put a property on the connection factory configuration.

As per the article [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) set `factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);` and `factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(10000);` on the factory and the rabbit client will try to reconnect when the rabbit server is down or the connection is lost.

Because you are using spring configuration for the connection factory your connection factory will be like the following

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="somehost"/>
    <property name="username" value="guest"/>
    <property name="password" value="guest"/>
    <property name="automaticRecoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="networkRecoveryInterval" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Connection factory reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#connections)

Comment: Thanks for answeing, but the problem seems to be more than connection recovery (I edited my code and it still doesn't work after re-connect). The bean of the rpcServer (and the client) seem to be unusable after the connection is established again.